# How to compare the similarity of 2 transfer functions

Tags: transfer-function, control-systems

I'm working on a power systems where I have 2 linearized transfer functions. The first transfer function corresponds to the no-load case and the second transfer function corresponds to the full-load case.

I was wondering if there are metrics to compare 2 transfer functions, for example how similar are their respective poles and zeroes.

I can play on some factors, like inductance and switching frequency and I get the feeling that increasing the inductance value too much makes the 2 transfer functions more dissimilar.

Regards

Comment: https://se.mathworks.com/help/robust/ref/gapmetric.html

Comment: I don't have this toolbox. But I will try to learn more about this algorithm.